# Select interaction stopDown

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I'm looking for a way to have the 'stopDown' feature of PointerInteraction/DrawInteraction work for Select interaction.
I have an attached click listener on the map, which should not fire when the select interaction is added to the map.

I've tried to stop event propagation upon click/pointerdown/pointerup but it seems to stop any map panning from working.

How to accomplish 'stopDown' for Select interaction?

Answer (score 0):

I use a workaround of a mouseOver var (set either by a pointMove interaction or map event) to determine if the mouse is over feature then testing it in map click events.

e.g.

```
var mouseOver;

map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
     mouseOver = (map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel).length > 0);
});

map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {

    if (mouseOver()) { return; }

    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....

});
```

In more complex cases you would need to add/remove a pointerMove select interaction for each click select interaction you add/remove which does nothing except set mouseOver

```
var interHover = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
    style: function(feature) {
        // return the unselected style
    },
    filter: // same as click select interaction
});

interHover.on( "select", function(evt) { mouseOver = (evt.selected.length > 0); });
```

Comment: Wouldn't work for my case since im adding & removing the select interaction (it isn't always added to the map). So when the select interaction isn't active, the user should be able to click on the map just like before, I can't simply check for any features at the coordinate.